# External deployment configuration with terraform and helm

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm quite new to terraform so my problem might be naive but still, I do not know how to solve it.
I have a terraform script that uses helm_release (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/r/release.html) problem is that I have deployment configuration in a separate git repository. Let's say: https://project.git/configuration.
What I would like to achieve is to be able to add all files from e.g. https://project.git/configuration/dev (for dev env deployment) to config map.
The structure of terraform module is:

```
+project
+-helm
+--templates
+---configmap.yaml
+---deployment.yaml
+---ingress.yaml
+---service.yaml
+--chart.yaml
+--values.yaml
+-helm.tf
+-other tf files
```

I need all files from the configuration repository to be placed under

```
+project
+-helm
+--configuration
```

As only then i'm able to use this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
...
data:
{{- (.Files.Glob "configuration/*").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
```

in my configmap.yaml, helm requires those files to be placed in chart directory.

Comment: I'm also keen of making https: // project.git/configuration a terraform module. So I can use it as a submodule. But the problem remains the same, how to make those files available in project/helm/configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries... I came with the simplest solution there is. I used `.gitmodules` (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). During projects git clone, the configuration is available as a submodule in ./project/helm/configuration. No terraform tricks required. The only thing that had to be done, and is a bit implicit is that specific git setting had to be set to force submodule download during clone (by default directory is empty).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the Helm `.Files` mechanism for files that are actually bundled with the chart proper, not external configuration you're trying to inject.

If you're planning to use Terraform to manage everything, one option is to have Terraform create a [kubernetes_config_map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/config_map.html) that has the file content you need, and pass a reference to that `${kubernetes_config_map.with_the_files.name}` to the Helm chart.

If you want to principally use Helm, but pass the files in externally, you can pass those as values.  If you have Helm `values.yaml` syntax:

```yaml
configFiles:
  test.yaml: |
    key: value
    key2: value2
```

You can emit that into a ConfigMap.  You could iterate over the `configFiles`, or use the lightly-documented Helm `toYaml` extension to just render the whole thing.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "mychart.name" . }}
data:
{{ .Values.configFiles | toYaml | indent 2 }}
```

Once you've done that, you can pass these in via `helm install --set` options, or the equivalent Terraform `helm_release` [`set_string`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/r/release.html#set_string) setting:

```
resource "helm_release" "chart" {
  name = "chart"
  chart = "..."
  set_string {
    name = "configFiles.test\\.yaml"
    value = "${file("${path.module}/test.yaml")}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. This looks great. I overengineered my solution a bit but your approach looks easier and I will try it for sure. What I currently did is that I made configuration repository a minimal terraform module (takes the environment name as input and returns the full path to deployment configuration directory e.g. ${path.module}/dev)
In the main terraform, I'm just copying all the files from there using local exec (in null_resource) to the directory where the helm is and call helm_release. Works, but IMHO just smells bad.